# Cannot get on http://localhost:3000/

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I am using gulp.The tasks are getting run creating required folders. But I get Cannot GET/ error when run in browser.I have attached the image of my project structure and also the output in command line[image: command line output].[image: Project Structure] .My index.html contains the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="helloWorldApp">
    <head>
        <title>Angular hello world app</title>
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <ng-view class="view"></ng-view>
    </body>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

I want to know why it cannot get or not routed properly and what should be done. So the problem is when the server is running on localhost and I hit  localhost:3000/ in browser it says cannot get with a white background.Following is my gulpfile.js

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

const scripts = require('./scripts');
const styles = require('./styles');

var devMode = false;



gulp.task('css',function(){
    gulp.src(styles)
        .pipe(concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream : true
    }))
});

gulp.task('js',function(){
    gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream : true
    }))
});

gulp.task('html',function(){
    gulp.src('./templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/html'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream : true
    }))
});

gulp.task('build',function(){

    gulp.start(['css','js','html']);
     console.log("finshed build");
});

gulp.task('browser-sync',function(){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        open : false,
        server : {
            baseDir : 'dist'
        }
    });
     console.log("finshed browser ");
});

gulp.task('start',function(){
    devMode = true;
    gulp.start(['build','browser-sync']);
    gulp.watch(['./css/**/*.css'],['css']);
    gulp.watch(['./js/**/*.js'],['js']);
    gulp.watch(['./templates/**/*.html'],['html']); 
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but your questions isn't clear enough for us to understand what your problem is! What is your error and when does it happen? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Why do you pass null as the first argument to browser-sync and what is open: false supposed to do?

Comment: open : false is to avoid the tab to open directly without request. and null is not required.

Comment: @Hampus can you resolve my query?

Comment: Have you've had a look at @lofihelsinki's suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your baseDir is 'dist' you need to run http://localhost:3000/html in the browser I think that should work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to point `browserSync` to the `dist/html/index.html` file as the start page with `index`.

```
gulp.task('browser-sync',function(){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        open : false,
        server : {
            baseDir : 'dist',
            index : "html/index.html"
        }
     });
     console.log("finshed browser ");
});
```

Comment: Are you in the right directory? What does `http://localhost:3000` say if you enable directory listing? Replace `index : "html/index.html"` with `directory: true`